# laravel phpunit db connection in tearDownAfterClass

Tags: laravel, phpunit

how to call `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` methods in `tearDownAfterClass` function?
I get error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::select()`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public static function tearDownAfterClass(): void
    {
        $databases = DB::select("SHOW DATABASES LIKE '". env('SCHEMA_PREFIX')."%'",[]);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem myself, the only solution was a wierd hack found at
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/seedingunseeding-the-database-once-per-test-class?page=1#reply=609036

adds `(new self())->setUp` in tearDownAfterClass :

```php
public static function tearDownAfterClass(): void
{
  (new self())->setUp();
  DB:statement('stuff');//works now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define your own setUp / tearDown methods within a test class, be sure to call the respective parent::setUp() / parent::tearDown() methods on the parent class. Just place your setup logic after parent is called. Tested in Laravel 8.x

```
/**
 * Setup test
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function setUp() : void
{
    parent::setUp();
}




/**
 * Tear down test
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function tearDown() : void
{
    parent::tearDown();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and may be, it can be like this:

```
public static function tearDownAfterClass(): void
{
  self::setUp();
  DB:statement('stuff');//works now
}
```